# How to achieve Scale Breaks in Plotly, or have a logarithmic scale

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

[image]

I want to achieve Scale Breaks in Plotly. I've researched and know that there is no way to do this exactly in plotly.js. Is there any way to achieve a similar behavior? Graphs with outlier data are difficult to analyze without this. I have checked and there seems to be no way to even show a logarithmic scale in plotly.js

Comment: [log axes](https://plotly.com/javascript/axes/#logarithmic-axes) are supported

Comment: That works but does not look as good as the graph above. Is there any way to create a custom axis?